# Add percentage sign labels on bargraph labels by calculating percentage value between two column values in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
year <- c("2015", "2016", "2017", "2018")
malaria_mortality <- c(25, 30, 35, 40)
malaria_discharge <- c(155, 340, 550, 160)

fatality <- data.frame(year, malaria_mortality,malaria_discharge )
```

I want to generate percentage proportion by calculating value from *malaria mortality column* to  value from *malaria discharge column*, Which i achieve by doing this:

```
fatality$case_fatal <- round((fatality$malaria_mortality/fatality$malaria_discharge) * 100, 2)
```

I then went ahead and generated a plot that looks like this

```
p <-ggplot(fatality, aes(x=year, y=case_fatal)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="steelblue")+
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title="Case Fatality ") +
  geom_text(aes(label=case_fatal), vjust=1.6, color="white",
            position = position_dodge(0.9), size=3.5)

p
```

Everything is okey, however, how can I add **percentage sign (%)** to the bargraph labels. Any assistance to add percentage sign on bar labels will be appreciated

Comment: Use `aes(label=paste0(case_fatal, "%")` in the `geom_text` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mohanasundaram said right in the comments, you can use `paste0` with `"%"` or any other sign to add to your labels like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
p <-ggplot(fatality, aes(x=year, y=case_fatal)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="steelblue")+
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title="Case Fatality ") +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(case_fatal, "%")), vjust=1.6, color="white",
            position = position_dodge(0.9), size=3.5)

p
```

Output:

[image]